# Encoding insert-value Oracle

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, encoding, insert

I've some date from file and I'm inserting this to DB Oracle.

The problem is an example:

- Column type VARCHAR2, size 3 bytes
- I've tried to insert 'абв' and saw the exception: ORA-12899: value too large for column (actual: 6, maximum: 3)

That's because each character is encoded in two bytes. Okay now we will re-encode. The database is encoded AL32UTF8. The encoding of the file is CP866.

An attempt to unsuccessfully recode:

```
Encoding srcEncodingFormat = Encoding.GetEncoding(866);
Encoding dstEncodingFormat = Encoding.UTF8;
byte[] originalByteString = srcEncodingFormat.GetBytes(s);
byte[] convertedByteString = Encoding.Convert(srcEncodingFormat,
dstEncodingFormat, originalByteString);
s = dstEncodingFormat.GetString(convertedByteString);
```

We can't change the column type. We can't use `VARCHAR2(3 CHAR)` either. How can I solve it? Is it possible to explicitly specify the encoding of the value to add when data is inserted into the database?

```
NLS_LANGUAGE    AMERICAN
NLS_TERRITORY   AMERICA
NLS_CURRENCY    $
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY    AMERICA
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS  .,
NLS_CHARACTERSET    AL32UTF8
NLS_CALENDAR    GREGORIAN
NLS_DATE_FORMAT DD-MON-RR
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE   AMERICAN
NLS_SORT    BINARY
NLS_TIME_FORMAT HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT    DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT  HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY   $
NLS_COMP    BINARY
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS    BYTE
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP FALSE
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  AL16UTF16
NLS_RDBMS_VERSION   11.2.0.2.0
```

This is my NLS parameters. The fact is that the boss strictly forbid something to be changed at the database level. Excuse me is there any way to do without this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately what you want to do can not be achieved: 
Your string 'абв' requires 6 byte in AL32UTF8 characterset. 
You only allow your column to contain up to 3 byte. 
You can not define a specific characterset for a column.

Every time you provide the database a string in a specific encoding, it translates it automatically to the correct representation in it's characterset. This is a feature so you can insert (and query) with different clients in different characterset settings but always get the correct encoding.

This leads to an ugly trick which is possible in some clients (I don't know about c#): 
When sending a set of characters to the database, you tell it, the string is the same characterset as the databases NLS_CHARACTERSET. As there is no conversion needed, often the string isn't checked as well, just inserted into the row. 
As long as the string is only selected by the same client (with the same characterset as the database) everything seems fine. 
But whenever the string is used inside the database (most likely somewhere in the WHERE part of the query) unforeseen results will appear. The same is true if any client with another encoding will ever try to access this data. 
This is why I recommend **not** to implement such hacks.

Comment: For .NET it depends which driver/provider you use in your application. Some inherit setting from `NLS_LANG` (e.g. ODP.NET unmanged driver), other rely on current Windows locale (e.g. ODP.NET Managed Driver) and other use always UTF-16 (e.g. OraOLEDB from Oracle).

Comment: In deed, such hack is not recommended. Also it would not work in your case anyway. For example, if you transfer `абв` byte-wise as CP866 then this would let to invalid UTF-8 characters (i.e. non valid byte values) which Oracle will instantly replace by placeholder (e.g. `¿`). Mentioned hack may only work if your database character set covers **any** byte value, for example all ISO8859-x encoding's or the Windows CPxxxx